# How to render all child components at once while using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to render all child components of my App components to the page.

**What i have done**

I made `App` (parent) component inside it has `{this.props.children}` and in my `main.js` (where i use Router) i have:

```js
render(<Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="/blog" component={MiniBlog} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            </Route>
        </Router>,
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);
```

This does the react-router job pretty well, as components switch when i click their corresponding route.

**Behaviour Needed**

I need all child components to display on the page(at once, say, stacked.) so i can animate to the active component with routes (kind of scrolling animation), instead of switching through active components.

I'm not sure if `react-router` is the perfect fit for this, but I'm open for any suggestions on how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: if only want to animate transition, you can use ReactCSSTransitionGroup, without  displaying all child components at once

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i'm checking ReactCssTransitionGroup right now. @Utro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [react-router original example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/animations)

Just update your CSS so instead of fade in-out it will be slide in-out e.g.

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  left: -1000px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in, left 1s;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
}

.example-leave {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in, left 1s;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 1000px;
}
```

Also adjust appropriate **ReactCSSTransitionGroup** transition properties e.g.

```
transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
```